# Copy spreadsheet with google script and set permission to each sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

can u help me and is it really impossible in google script?
We got:
Spreadsheet 1

- sheet1 - permission to edit AAA@gmail.com
- sheet2 - permission to edit BBB@gmail.com
  Then we create a copy with name "Spreadsheet 2" running script inside Spreadsheet1:

```
file.makeCopy(name, destination);
```

and I need to save permission to edit Spreadsheet2 in same way: sheet1 for AAA and sheet2 for BBB

Found this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/#permission but it works on a drive level.

Tnx for help

P.S. this thing can help, but how to implement when creating a copy to new spreadsheet? and give permission to run the script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()

Comment: Not really. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditoremailaddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Share the copied file with your desired editors with [addEditors(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditorsemailaddresses).
- Get the copied file `ID` via [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getid) and use that to retrieve the spreadsheet.
- Protect each sheet from everyone except the user running the script and your desired editor, using [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection).

#### Code sample:

```
var newFile = file.makeCopy(name, destination);
newFile.addEditors(["AAA@gmail.com", "BBB@gmail.com"]);
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newFile.getId());
var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
protectSheet(sheet1, "AAA@gmail.com");
protectSheet(sheet2, "BBB@gmail.com");
```

Where `protectSheet` is:

```
function protectSheet(sheet, editor) {
  var protection = sheet.protect();
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  protection.addEditor(editor);
}
```